# How to run an Eco Server on the Pi

Tags: server

The kickstarter game [Eco](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1037798999/eco-global-survival-game/description). I am wondering how to run a server from the Pi.
I successfully ran a Minecraft server on the Pi but that has a tutorial. Anyone know how to get me started to create one for this game? I would imagine that it would require less computing power but I don't know much about this type of stuff.

Comment: A link to the game's home page would be helpful. Is this game designed for the Pi?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no this is not possible. On the kickstarter page's FAQs is the following list of requirements:

```
Client Requirements: 
Intel Core i3 or AMD equivalent 
DX9 capable video card 
1GB HDD space


Server Requirements: 
Varies depending on desired world size. 
Intel Core i5 or AMD equivalent. The more CPUs the better. 
4GB of ram 
1GB HDD space
```

The Pi does not meet the minimum CPU requirements to operate as a client or server, nor does it have the required RAM for a server. The CPU requirement also indicates that the game is compiled for the x86/x64 architecture which is not the same architecture as the Pi's arm architecture. More info on [architecture differences](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/140986024839/installing-applications-on-a-raspberry-pi-running) can be found on our blog.